# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express connection error

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, odbc

Hi I'm having issues with SQL connection for a client PC
We have software that uses SQL database, and I have just updated from SQL2005 to SQL2008

We have 5 pcs:

- 2 x vista (32 bit)
- 2 x win7 (64bit)
- 1 x xp (32bit))

The SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is installed on one of the win7 pcs.

All other client PCs connect via ODBC system DNS with auth user/pass.

All client PCs connect and test successfully via ODBC test.

However the win7 client pc (not the server pc) returns the below error message when starting the software. Even though the ODBC test is ok.

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen
(Connect()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

TCP/IP and Named pipes are enabled in the sql server config.

I have installed new sql native odbc driver on all machines.

windows firewall is disabled, and a kaspersky one is enabled, but doubt that's an issue due to other pcs being able to connect.

I'm lost it's only this win7 64bit client pc that can't connect. All settings the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of "telnet severip 1433" from one of the client PCs

Comment: Are you sure the configuration is the same? SQL Express has TCP connections disabled by default, you have to use Named Pipes. This error usually occurs when you're trying to use TCP instead of Named Pipes. Also, can the client connect to the server's CIFS (eg, can you run "\\server_name" from the client and get something besides an error)?

Comment: @chris S  sorry new to this sql stuff, the ODBC is set to server name
i.e. my sql server is pc is called HP-5. because the sql is at default named instance, its not HP-5/MSSQLSERVER, instead its just HP-5. all ODBC settings are the same across all client pcs, ditto driver. and tcp and named pipes are turned on the server. only pc that can't connect is a win7 64bit one.
I have updated the SQL native clent drivers across all pcs.